# C# WPF ComboBox Mouse over color

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

When the mouse hover over my ComboBox, I get an awful blue/lightblue pair of color for the backgroung of my ComboBox.
I tried the solutions here :[ComboBox Mouse over color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140067/combobox-mouse-over-color), [WPF Combobox Mouse Over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913211/wpf-combobox-mouse-over), [How to style ComboBox Background on Mouse Hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564104/how-to-style-combobox-background-on-mouse-hover) or [WPF combobox default hover color on togglebutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892005/wpf-combobox-default-hover-color-on-togglebutton), but it doesn't change anything, I still get the default colors while hovering.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you all in advance,
Demasiado.

Here is the XAML code :

```
<Window x:Class="Homepage.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="TileZoomIn">
            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="10" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="TileZoomOut">
            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="1" To="10" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <DropShadowEffect x:Key="DropShadowEffect" BlurRadius="20" Opacity="1" ShadowDepth="0" Color="White"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <ComboBox Name="comboBoxTRIG" FontSize="40" Width="210" Height="98" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="40,-180,0,256" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0">
            <ComboBox Margin="25" Width="130" Height="50">
                <ComboBox.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
                </ComboBox.Resources>
            </ComboBox>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: post your XAML code also

Comment: Welcome to a good start on SO - this is an example of well-conducted research and a well-formatted question.

Comment: Do you have any resource dictionaries in your App.xaml? Possibly overriding the default style for your combo box? Also, why a combo box iwthin a combo box?

Comment: create a ComboBoxItem style with a trigger for IsMouseOver and assign it as ItemContainerStyle

Comment: @Michel Ciechan : comboBox inside a comboBox is a mistake, cause I changed the code like 1 billion times, so at a made a bad copy paste. There is no trick, nothing particular, I just want to change the default color of the comboBox when the mouse pointer is passing over it... I can't believe I already spend 3 days on only that point without making just one step in the good direction.
I don't understand your question about the App.xaml. What is a ressource dictionnary ? Sorry, english is not my mother tongue, sometimes it just doesn't help...

Comment: @Eran otzap : why ComboBoxItem ? My problem is on the comboBox itself

Comment: I thought because of the answer below .. , 
one sec

Comment: The answer below is due to a missunderstanding of my problem. As I say in my question, I have a comboBox, I just move the mouse pointer over it, then the problem begins. So, no comboBoxItems involved in this :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem arises from ButtonChrome in the ToggleButton's template. Remove it from the ToggleButton.

```
   ComboBox -> ToggleButton -> ButtonChrome
```

Steps :

1)  Open Expression Blend and edit a copy of ComboBox's Style , This will give you the Style of the ComboBox + it's Template and all it's TemplateParts , Among them is the problematic ToggleButton.

2)  Locate the ToggleButton and it's **Style** called "ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton" .

3)  In "ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton" replace the **Themes:ButtonChrome** with a **Border** (like shown in the 3'rd block of code below.)

**The ComboBox's default template (Simplified !):**

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">                                 
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup">
            .....
        </Popup>
        <ToggleButton  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"/>
        <ContentPresenter ... />
    </Grid>                     
</ControlTemplate>
```

**The toggle button Style + Template (Simplified !).**

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">     
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" ....>
                    <Grid>
                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" />
                    </Grid>
                </Themes:ButtonChrome>  
             </ControlTemplate>             
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What you need to do is to override the default ComboBox template and edit the toggle button's style by replacing ButtonChrome with a Border :

```
 <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
              <Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid>
                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>               
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: It says it doesnt' know "DownArrowGeometry".
You wrote 3 code samples, so I have to copy the 1st one and the 3rd one, right ?

Comment: Does it atlist recognize 
"..."  ??

Comment: you copy nothing . it was simplified with an "!" so it's really simplified .

google : override default style and template wpf . and change the template

Comment: I don't get you, sorry.

Comment: Ok . 

1) Do you know what a Style is in WPF ?
2) and a ControlTemplate ?

Comment: 1&2 : quite, but I don't understand all the lines inside. Some are clear, some I don't get what they do. And I didn't expect to have to.

Comment: 1 ) ComboBox's default template , in there you see a toggle button with a style.  'ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton'
2) 'ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton' Style
3) The change you need to make in 'ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton'  
    in order to remove the ButtonChrome which is the cause of your problem .

Comment: @Encore i tried to make it clearer , see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can override `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` within the `ComboBox` scope:

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

[image: sample]

the entire XAML can be something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Margin="25" Width="130" Height="50">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Path="Collection" Source="{StaticResource viewmodel}"/>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

A followup to your comment:

ignore the `viewmodel` and my `ItemSource` you should use your own, this was just for the demonstration.

as for your comment about

> I could not get anything to work

i would suggest that you will create a new project and test only this XAML (with your ItemSource of course) and see if you can get the result you want.
when you will get that, you can move to your real project and see where the styles changes and where is the problem exists.

EDIT#2:

In order to change the color of the `ToggleButton` i think is best to override the entire `ComboBox` Style.

[image]

i used the

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton"
                 TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
```

The rest of the code and style taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.100).aspx).

i would recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610339/combobox-mouseover) as well.

Comment: My XAML is already coded this way, it doesn't work.
The only difference is that I don't have the <ComboBox.ItemsSource> tag. But when I write it says it doesn't know "viewmodel".
I tried eveything I found on stackoverflow, I could not get anything to work.

Comment: So I did, new empty project, just copied the line you wrote above. Still no progress, default bi-color(blue) highlight color, whatever I try.
By the way, I don't know how to mention my own viewmodel, so I justed deleted the <ComboBox.ItemsSource> block.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: when you talk about that blue color highlight, is it on the selected-item or the button itself? can you please post the XAML and CS of the new project you made?

Comment: now i understand, my example was referring to the Selected-Item highlight and not to the button itself. (you can clearly see this in the Print Screen i uploaded as the button is highlighted in blue and the SelectedItem is green)

Comment: Oh, yes. The green color. What I clearly saw was the exact same blue color of the ComboBox, I was focused on that...

Comment: Thanks for your help Sag1v, I already looked at this MSDN page for another problem. I'm not skilled enough to understand what I should keep and what I can leave,
For example, I copied the whole MSDN code sample, tried to change the ControlMouseOverColor to 0xFF000000 or 0XFFFFFFFF but it doesn't change anything. I really have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

There it no item in my ComboBox in the test project. I just hover the mouse over it and the whole control is blue.
Here is the .cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="comboBoxTRIG" FontSize="40" Width="210" Height="98" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="42,38,0,184" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0">
            <ComboBox Width="130" Height="50">
                <ComboBox.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
                </ComboBox.Resources>
            </ComboBox>
        </ComboBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your comboxItem Template in your window resources

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>

                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" 
                            Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
```